# Selenium IDE - can't select "table" tab

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why I can't select the "table" tab?

Here is a pic:

[alt text http://img110.imageshack.us/img110/935/imgzx.jpg](http://img110.imageshack.us/img110/935/imgzx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "Format" are you using? The table is available in HTML only. I think.

Select Options/Format/HTML from the menu and the Table tab should be activated.